# Acess User Information from Appointment Schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am a newbie to ExpressJs and NodeJS . I am trying to fetch my userInformation to Appointment schema. How would I access my user schema from appointment schema? I am quite sure that we will have to use populate, But I am not aware of how to use it

Appointment Schema

```
var appointmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    visitType : String,
    timeDuration : String,
    startTime : Date,
    endTime : Date,
    status : String

  });
```

User Schema :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  prefix : String,
  firstName : String,
  middleName : String,
  lastName : String,
  dob : String,
  age : Number,
  gender : String
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll assume that the names of those **TWO** above schemas are `Appointment` and `User` respectively, so far there is nothing relates those schemas with each other, so:

***First thing***: You need to mention that `userId` attribute in `Appointment` schema refers to `User` schema as follow:

```
userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

instead of:

```
userId: String,
```

***Second thing***: On trying to fetch your userInformation from `Appointment schema`, your query will be:

```
Appointment
  .find({ /* whatever your filters options */ })
  .populate('userId')
  .exec()
```

Read more about **mongoose population**: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Shouldn't we have to add _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Appoinment' }, in the User Schema as well . @Basim Hennawi

Comment: What is the relation between `User` and `Appointment`? 1:1? 1:N? Also what is `_id` attribute in User schema refers to? userId or appointmentId?

Comment: 1 : N, and _id from User  is the userId in the appointment Schema.

Comment: You don't need to write this `_id` attribute at all explicitly because mongoose do this for your schema by default. Read more: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: But this would give validation error  if existing userId is available. Am I right? in order to confirm that the process that I am working on is fine @Basim Hennawi